# How to get only a set of values from arrays in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range

I have  an array of size(5)

```
 x=[[[10.566],[23.6767],[56.667]],[[12.666],[23.2232],[21.2323]],[[12.77],[12.4444],[23.1222]],[[12.233],[12.2233],[14.555]],[[12.3232],[23.334],[34.344]]]
```

How to get arrays from 2nd array to 4th array using for loop?

```
for i in range(5):
        print(x[i][1:5])
```

What I actually want is

```
   [[[12.666],[23.2232],[21.2323]],[[12.77],[12.4444],[23.1222]],[[12.233],[12.2233],[14.555]]]
```

How to get a specific arrays from a for-loop ?

Comment: @Ruturaj, no `x[1:5]`.

Comment: Could you include your whole array instead of the partial array here to make it more clear of how the structure look like, also what your sample output looks like

Comment: ? Please post the entire array without formatting shortcuts as `..`

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh  Updated

Comment: Your output has a bracket missing @binz please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array slicing:

```py
In [1]: x=[[[10.566],[23.6767],[56.667]],[[12.666],[23.2232],[21.2323]],[[12.77],[12.4444],[23.1222]],[[12.233],[12.2233],[14.555]],[[12.3232],[23.334],[34.344]]]                                                                                            

In [3]: x[1:4]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[3]: 
[[[12.666], [23.2232], [21.2323]],
 [[12.77], [12.4444], [23.1222]],
 [[12.233], [12.2233], [14.555]]]
```

Comment: But What if I need arrays from 4 to 6 with a total of 10 arrays.?

Comment: Please be more specific. Post your input and expected output.